# How does NetSuite calculate inventory?

Tags: netsuite

we recently connected to our NetSuite using ODBC so we can navigate tables and query the database. I'm having difficulty determining how NS calculates inventory levels.

I noticed the table "Item_Location_Map" has quantity on hand which seems accurate, but I don't see a way to specify at what point in time. I figured maybe it calculates real time based on all transactional data but ran into another issue. All the details for a transaction are on the Transactions table and Tranaction_Lines except for...oddly enough...the quantity.

If I look up a say invoices and pull in the quantity field, it is always empty. Some invoices have a quantity_packed or quantity_picked value but that doesn't really help.

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

A couple ways.

Stock Ledger and Inventory Valuation reports (not saved searches), which you can use through `N/query`.

Inventory Activity Detail saved search, which you can best use by setting the "Is Inventory Affecting" column criteria to true.

As for how that looks in the database, I am not certain, unfortunately. Also, I highly advise against using ODBC for something like this. A restlet or suitelet would be infinitely faster and more helpful.